# How to Send a XMLHttpRequest.responseXml to a JSP file after editing it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I am having a xml file. I am loading the xml file using AJAX and making changes to the responseXml by adding new elements to it. Now i want to overwrite the xml file with modified xml document by sending it to a jsp page. How to send the modified responseXml object to a jsp page?

Comment: Post or get the jsp that can receive a posted or get'ed xml file.
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=send+xml+to+jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you already calling from a jsp, then put some dummy div like

```
<div id='abc'></div>
```

and then once u get a response after success add line as

```
document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML = response;
```

Let me know If u use any framework....

Comment: What does this have to do with sending an xml file back to the server after changing it?

Comment: server? You asked about sending to JSP right?.. after getting the response to display push it in div

Comment: OP asked about sending an XML to a JSP (which of course is on the server) after having modified it. Nothing else

Comment: I think its his destination to display it. Lets wait for his reply

Comment: What is there to wait for? _Now i want to overwrite the xml file with modified xml document by sending it to a jsp page_

Comment: Hi all,I am just adding and removing some elements from the xml document by DOM and then i want to send to jsp and overwrite the xml file...

Comment: Actually the scenario is... I want to display a page according to a xml file.. Like a list of books retrieved from that xml. Then I want to add some books details to that xml file and whenever I save it.. the xml file shud change so that it ll show the newly added books next time i visit the page...

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this

[How to send a XML doc to server from client in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571768/how-to-send-a-xml-doc-to-server-from-client-in-jquery)